# jax-rs 1.1 with security filter and dependency injection, how to achieve this?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi, servlet-filters

For example I have the following **JAX-RS 1.1** method which receives [JWT token](https://jwt.io/), check it and then process or deny request like following:

```
@GET
public Response getBook(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorizationToken, @QueryParam("id") String bookId) {

    //if(authorizationToken is a valid JWT token)
    //      get User object which represented by this token
    //      get required book from database
    //      return 200 code with a book within response
    //else if(authorizationToken is invalid by whatever reason it's)
    //      return 401 code within a response
    //else if(database error)
    //      return 500 code within a response

}
```

As you can see in every jax-rs method I need to use same lines of code: *check token*, *transform it to `User` object*, *return 401 error if it isn't valid*.

Actually I can optimise it by extracting it in a static method which will perform this check and return `User` object upon success or throw an `Exception` if something went wrong. Also I can create [webfilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) which will check header and validate token before it reached jax-rs method and will abort it with 401 exception if it isn't valid.

But I'd like to achieve all together. `Webfilter` which will validate JWT token and if it's valid **convert it** to `User` object and **inject it** in jax-rs method as following:

```
@GET
public Response getBook(@RequestByUser User user, @QueryParam("id") String bookId) {

    //if(get required book from database was successfull)
    //      return 200 code with a book within response
    //else(database error)
    //      return 500 code within a response
}
```

So if I reached that point I can be sure that User is valid and I don't need to care about it. Is it possible to achieve this with **JAX-RS 1.1**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do exactly what you want here but it wouldn't be too hard to implement something with some [thread local data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).  Basically, the filter would store the ThreadLocal data with the User information and the service methods would be able to get it.  It's a bit of a hack but it would let you do what you want.

Be careful though - thread local data lives along with the thread - try not to store a giant object in there or you may run into memory issues if you have a ton of clients.

**EDIT**

After thinking about this a bit, why not just use the session?  ThreadLocal assumes that the filter and the service run on the same thread.  This is *likely* to be true but not guaranteed.

So in your filter:

*JWTFilter.java*

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/*"}
public class JWTFilter implements Filter {
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                             ServletResponse response,
                             FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String jwt = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        User user = getUserFromJWT(jwt);  // you'll have to code this
        if(user != null) {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else {
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
}
```

*YourService.java*

```
@GET
public Response getBook(@QueryParam("id") String bookId,
                        @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute("user");    
}
```

Notice the "cheat" here - we're injecting the HttpServletRequest so that we can get the session and, with it, the user.  But because of the filter this method will not be called if the JWT validation failed.

This code does not take advantage of anything outside of the JAX-RS and/or Servlet spec and should be app server agnostic.

Comment: Hi, WebFilter is from which package.Is it a part of JAX-RS 1.1?.JAX-RS 1.1 is already in classpath however WebFilter import could not resolve. Could you please he;p ?

Comment: For anyone looking, `WebFilter` is part of the `javax.servlet` packages

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter and/or interceptor for this purpose. Here is the [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) example.

```
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
                    throws IOException {

        final SecurityContext securityContext =
                    requestContext.getSecurityContext();
        if (securityContext == null ||
                    !securityContext.isUserInRole("privileged")) {

                requestContext.abortWith(Response
                    .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .entity("User cannot access the resource.")
                    .build());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned that I need solution for jax-rs 1.1, `ContainerRequestFilter` available since 2.0 only https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html